# How can I create a shiny object in three.js?

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js

i want to make a Cube in with three.js with a shiny (like on a silver/gold medal) surface.
Is there any special material which I can use (like meshbasicmaterial..) or how am i able to do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like this tutorial shows you how to do pretty much exactly this: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-interactive-liquid-metal-ball-webgl ([demo](http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/reactive-ball/))

Comment: Just to state the obvious, make sure you've got light sources/other objects in the scene for it to reflect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this material:

```
THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } )
```

I got it from [here](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_cars.html). I think for this to work as you want it to, there have to be some other objects in your scene to reflect. Otherwise, it won't really look impressive.

Edit: I changed it to what mrdoob suggested. It's his library, so I would definitely go with his opinion.

Comment: I think `MeshPhonMaterial` should be the one Applecow is after.